# Install social login with angular 12

Tags: angular, node-modules, google-signin, package.json

I'm new in angular, since a week i'm facing an issue while installing the package angularx-social-login in my project. I'm using Angular 12 because i'have a pro version of MDBootsrap Angular 4 (which it uses 12 version of Angular). I was able to instal the angularx-social-login angular, unfortunaly it doens't work properly (the version is deprecated) . the newest package for angular login is @abacritt/angularx-social-login which it can't solve my problem since it only available for Angular 13 ou 14 project.
i tried to upgrade my angular version but , but it seems i got some errors beaucause of conflict version with Mdb4.I realy don't know how i can to figure it out this issue , please some help.

[image: Error using angularx-social-login]

[image: My MDB package.jsonpackage.json]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

change your node version to 14 or 12 using nvm

1. Install nvm
2. Then in your cmd list the nvm using `nvm ls`
3. Use the required version using `nvm use 14.15.0` or `nvm use 12`

this will solve your problem